# LeetCode Reverse Words in a String without using any java library

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

The following problem is from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string-iii/):

> Given a string, you need to reverse the order of characters in each
>   word within a sentence while still preserving whitespace and initial
>   word order.
>
> Example 1: Input: "Let's take LeetCode contest"
>
> Output: "s'teL ekat edoCteeL tsetnoc"

The following code is working correctly, but its runtime is 8 ms, which is only faster than 42.44% of Java online submissions. **How to make the following code faster?**

```
class Solution {
    public String reverseWords(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int length = s.length();
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        while(start < length){
            while( (end < length) && (s.charAt(end) != ' ')){
                end++;
            }
            doReverse(s, start, end -1, sb);
            start = ++end;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void doReverse(String s, int start, int end, StringBuilder sb){
        if(start >0)
            sb.append(" ");
        while(end >= start){
            sb.append(s.charAt(end));
            end--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, I don't think the code is entirely correct, because some characters may be expressed with two code units, and those must not be reversed. See https://dzone.com/articles/the-right-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-java for more info. Good luck!

Comment: @Elegie if Leetcode accepted the results I guess we can consider it as working as intended?

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 6 → 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: if you look into `StringBuilder.reverse()` you'll encounter some extra work for some Unicode symbols needing two chars for a symbol (called a *surrogate pair*), which should *not* be reversed.

But let's not consider that.

- Provide exactly the needed capacity for StringBuilder.
- `sb.append(' ')` is faster than for `" "`.
- `end - 1` not needed.

So:

```
public String reverseWords(String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    if (length <= 1) {
        return s;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while (start < length) {
        while (end < length && s.charAt(end) != ' ') {
            ++end;
        }
        doReverse(s, start, end, sb);
        start = ++end;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private void doReverse(String s, int start, int end, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (start > 0)
        sb.append(' ');
    while (end > start){
        --end;
        sb.append(s.charAt(end));
    }
}
```

In general using toCharArray could be faster:

```
public String reverseWords(String str) {
    char[] s = s.toCharArray();
    int length = s.length;
    if (length <= 1) {
        return s;
    }
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while (start < length) {
        while (end < length && s.charAt(end) != ' ') {
            ++end;
        }
        doReverse(s, start, end);
        start = ++end;
    }
    return new String(s);
}

private void doReverse(char[] s, int start, int end) {
    while (--end > start){
        char ch = s[start];
        s[start] = s[end];
        s[end] = ch;
        ++start;
    }
}
```

If you would *inline* doReverse for extra speed, you would need a copy of the changing parameters.

```
    // doReverse(char[] s, int start, int end)
    int end2 = end;
    while (--end2 > start){
        char ch = s[start];
        s[start] = s[end2];
        s[end2] = ch;
        ++start;
    }
```

Now we should be twice as fast (wild guess).